# Classified ads website on Django framework

Tags: python, django

I am finalizing my classified ads website. Everything is working fine. How do I link everything together now that the project is almost complete. When I click on the home page button be directed there, because I can only navigate through pages when I write the URL link. I want the links and the buttons to be connected so as to have one wholesome project. The project is done on the Django framework.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to code the html for the button to go to that page. So in your html file your code for that button will look like

```
<a href="/page"><button> buttontext </button></a>
```